# Passing hyperparameters to a sagemaker pipeline training step at execution time?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

For sagemaker pipelines, how would I go about passing the training step hyperparameter at execution time?  Say I have an input paramteter set like

input_hyperparams = ParameterString(
name="input_hyperparams",
default_value="{}",
)

and I now want to pass this value to the training step. Im having issues because I get an error when trying to unpack input_hyperparams to the estimator like this

```
train_estimator.set_hyperparameters(**input_hyperparams)
```

I get error

```
Error sagemaker.estimator.Estimator.set_hyperparameters() argument after ** must be a mapping, not ParameterString
```

How can I pass the hyperparameters to the pipeline at execution time? I want to be able to rerun the training pipeline with different hyperparamter without having to rebuild the pipeline each time?

I was able to run it using

```
train_estimator.set_hyperparameters(
               myparam =  input_hyperparams.to_string()
        )
```

but that creates a nested hyperparam objects which causes issues with default training containers....

Answer (score 0):

When using ** it looks like you are expecting to pass a dictionary to the ParameterString. Instead pass multiple ParameterString values and set of hyperparameter on the estimator using the ParameterString.

You can't unpack the dictionary using ** through a Pipeline parameter.